# Add image below a certain class of element using css

Tags: javascript, css

**What I want to do:**

I want to add a "walkingMan" image **under** an element when its class is changed to `activeCell`. I know how to do it when the image is added to the front or back of the element using pseudo class, but as far as I know, there isn't something like `:below` that I can use to achieve the same effect. Is there a way in css I can use to micmic this?

**What I have done:**

I have added image below every upper cell and make it visible when the class is changed to `activeCell`. But I hope to find a more simple solution.

**What it looks like:**
[image]

**Code: [Simplified Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/147prwy5/)**

Comment: You post link to jsfiddle homepage, not your code.

Comment: @MateuszMarchel Oops, my bad. Already correct it. Thanks for the reminder ;)

Comment: You can create this `acitve` class with `:before` and make absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single pseudo element on the `.cell` element and place a background image on it when it's active.

```js
let activeIndex = 0;
const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cell')];
setInterval(() => {
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.classList.remove('activeCell')
  });
  cells[activeIndex].classList.add('activeCell');
  activeIndex = activeIndex === cells.length - 1 ? 0 : (activeIndex + 1);
}, 300)
```

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.activeCell {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.activeCell::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  top: 1.3em;
  left: calc(50% - .5em); /* Center the stickman. Position it half of its width before the parent center*/
  background-image: url('https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png');
  background-size:cover; /* Scale the stickman to completely cover the background area.  */
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class='top'>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
  <a class='cell'>One</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just fyi, seems there is a bug when you run that code snippet

Comment: @k2snowman69 "seems there is a bug" isn't very descriptive :D

Comment: Repro: Click the Run code snippet button. Actual result:

{
  "message": "Function expected",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 47,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: @k2snowman69 I assume your browser probably doesn't support arrow functions. Will add babel to accomodate.

Comment: Thanks!! This is the most feasible and most simple solution for me!

Comment: Glad to help mate 

Answer (score 2):

What about this: https://jsfiddle.net/147prwy5/3/

HTML

```
<div class="cell active">
  <a>One</a>
  <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png" alt="walkingMan" />
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <a>One</a>
  <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png" alt="walkingMan" />
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <a>One</a>
  <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png" alt="walkingMan" />
</div>
<div class="cell active">
  <a>One</a>
  <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png" alt="walkingMan" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cell a {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}

.cell.active a {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.cell img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.cell.active img {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> add `.RunManActive` Class for Active element

```js
//clicking  add active Class
$(".RunMan").click(function() {
  $(".RunMan").removeClass('RunManActive');
  $(this).toggleClass('RunManActive');
});

//timing add active Class
var i=0;
var $elm=$(".Animate");
setInterval(function(){ 
  $elm.removeClass('RunManActive');
  $elm.eq(i).toggleClass('RunManActive');
  i=$elm.length<=i?0:i+1; 
}, 1000);
```

```css
.RunMan{
 width:35px;
 height:35px;
 background-color:lightgray;
 border:3px solid #fff;
 float:left;
 position: relative;
}
.RunManActive{
 background-color:#eee;
 border:3px solid lightgray;
}
.RunManActive > div{
 width:35px;
 height:35px;
 position: absolute;
 background-image:url(http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Objects-Running-man-icon.png);
 background-size:cover;
 top:100%;
 margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="RunMan RunManActive"><div></div></div>
<div class="RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="RunMan"><div></div></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style=" width:100%">
<div class="Animate RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="Animate RunMan "><div></div></div>
<div class="Animate RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="Animate RunMan"><div></div></div>
<div class="Animate RunMan"><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a fan of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo classes mainly because I've personally noticed some oddities when trying to position things in Chrome vs IE (damn it IE!). Since most people here are going to give a solution using these pseudo classes (because that's somewhat what you asked) I thought I'd give a different solution using flexbox and more divs.

Not the most optimal for download size but I do like that it's not absolute positioning elements and if the squares get bigger or smaller it's pretty easy to handle that as a scss variable at the top of the file. This all uses only two values, your padding between boxes and the size of the boxes so it should be easy to update and maintain.

Anyway, have fun! Awesome question by the way :-)

```css
.blocks {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.block > .square {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background: grey;
}

.block > .space {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.block.activeCell > .space {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block activeCell"><div class="square"></div><div class="space"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div><div class="space"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div><div class="space"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div><div class="space"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div></div>
  <div class="block"><div class="square"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can toggle the class upon clicking with this:

```
$('.cell').click(function() { //catch clicks on .cell
  $('.cell').removeClass('activeCell'); //remove class "activeCell" from all
  $(this).addClass('activeCell'); //add class "activeCell" to .cell clicked
});
```

Apply `position: relative;` to `.top` and `.bottom`:

```
.top,
.bottom {
  position: relative;
}
```

And use the psuedoclass `:before` to create a image under the `.activeCell`

```
.activeCell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

And remove this:

```
.walkingMan {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

And this:

```
<img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png" alt="walkingMan" class='walkingMan'/>
```

And to add space between the divs `.top` and `.bottom` put a `<br>` between them.

```js
$('.cell').click(function() {
  $('.cell').removeClass('activeCell');
  $(this).addClass('activeCell');
});
```

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  position: relative;
}

.activeCell {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.activeCell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/01/17/704754_people_512x512.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='top'>
    <a class='cell activeCell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
    <a class='cell'>One</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, using **CSS** only. With `:target` selector you can apply a style to the element you need to hide / show.

```css
.container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
}

.link {
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #ccc;
}
.walking-man {
 display: none;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
}
#p1:target {
 display: block;
}
#p2:target {
 display: block;
}
#p3:target {
 display: block;
}
#p4:target {
 display: block;
}
  height: 90px;
  float: left;
}

.walking-man img {
  width: 100%;
}

.walkin-man:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="#p1" class="link"></a>
 <div id="p1" class="walking-man"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a href="#p2" class="link"></a>
 <div id="p2" class="walking-man"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a href="#p3" class="link"></a>
 <div id="p3" class="walking-man"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <a href="#p4" class="link"></a>
 <div id="p4" class="walking-man"></div>
</div>
```